# gRPC server request_iterator do not finish in loop (in case C# client Python Server)

Tags: grpc-python, grpc-c#

We are trying to apply gRPC bidirectional streaming. Proto:

```
message Request {
    oneof requestTypes{
        ConfigRequest configRequest = 1;
        DataRequest   dataRequest   = 2;
    }
}

message ConfigRequest {
    request_quantity = 1;
    ...
}

message DataRequest {
    string id              = 1;
    bytes  data            = 2;
    ...
}

service Service {
    rpc FuncService(stream Request)              returns (stream Response);
}
```

The client side is written in C# and contains asynchrony.
If necessary, I can clarify the client code.
The server side is in python. Python code:

```
def FuncServe(self, request_iterator, context):
    i = 0
    for request in request_iterator: 
        ...
        if (i==request_quantity):
            break
        i+=1
```

The problem is the server hangs in a loop on requests, so I introduced an if-break statement. So far, everything is working, but we would like to work out the option when not all the requests stated in the config have arrived. In this case, we cannot avoid suspension in the loop and catch it. Also, I was unable to move the loop into a separate thread to control the execution time, it ends due to an empty iterator.
I would be very grateful for help in this loop problem.